# How to echo a file path location in php

Tags: php, html

I am using a php script to browse the files and folders in my apache server.  I am using the follow index.php.   I will like to add at the folder path into the script and echo it location at the bottom of the page.   It is my intention to load it into a variable.

Thanks

```
 <?php  // open this directory  $myDirectory = opendir("."); // get each entry
       while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
           $dirArray[] = $entryName; 
       } // close directory closedir($myDirectory);

 //  count elements in array $indexCount = count($dirArray); Print
 ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

 // sort 'em sort($dirArray);

 // print 'em print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0
 class=whitelinks>\n");
 print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");

 // loop through the array of files and print them all for($index=0;
 $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
         if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
         print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
         print("<td>");  print(filetype($dirArray[$index])); print("</td>");
         print("<td>");  print(filesize($dirArray[$index])); print("</td>");
         print("</TR>\n");
     } } print("</TABLE>\n"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `scandir()`:

```
<?php
    foreach(scandir($myDirectory) as $filename ) {
        echo $myDirectory.'/'.$filename.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

OR using `glob()`:

```
<?php
foreach (glob($myDirectory,"*.*") as $filename) 
{
            echo $myDirectory.'/'.$filename.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you using $results for?

Comment: @loko edited now , it had no role , i deleted it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php realpath function to locate the actual location of the file.

```
realpath
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Answer (score 0):

found it.

```
$path = !empty($_REQUEST['path']) ? $_REQUEST['path'] : dirname(__FILE__); // the path the script should access
echo "<H2>Browsing Location: {$path}</H2>";
```